# Why does not C++ Compare require an integer as its return value?

Tags: c++, algorithm, std

According to [C++'s requirements of Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare), any `Compare` type function should return something that is `true` if the first arg is less than the second, otherwise `false`. This named requirement is used in many standard algorithms, e.g. `std::sort`, `std::map`, `std::set`, etc. However, many of them need to judge if two elements are "equal". As the reference says, the standard lib determines `a == b` iff `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`. Obviously it needs twice the time to judge equivalence.

As we know, `std::string::compare` method returns an `int` value representing "less", "equal" and "greater" by negative value, zero value and positive value respectively. This seems to be a good idea to express the three possible relationships between two values in just one operation. So my question is, why doesn't the standard lib require `Compare` to return an integer value or any other type that is able to express at least 3 independent values?

Comment: Many algorithms don't care about equivalence, eg. Most sorts

Comment: Because the requirements of `Compare` are about establishing an ordering (e.g. is one object considered less than another), not with establishing equivalence.   `std::sort()` for example, only cares about the ordering of elements of a range, not equivalence.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is because not all data types support the full semantics necessary to do a `std::string::compare`-style three-way comparison.

For example, take the `float` type.  That seems like a pretty good candidate for a three-way-comparison, until you realize that there are "special" floating point values like `NaN` that are neither greater than nor less than nor equal to any other floating point value.  It's not clear what a three-way-comparison function should return if one or both of its operands is `NaN`; OTOH the `Compare` function's expected behavior is clear:  it should return false.

Comment: In my opinion, it's not important whether `NaN` is **naturally** greater than or less than or equal to other values, but important whether you want it to be. Just like what @Peter said, `Compare` are about ordering. For example, in a sorting, if you want all `NaN` values to be placed at the end, then clearly your comparator should tell that `NaN` is larger than any other value. In many practices we treat two `NaN`s equal so our comparator can simply tell that they are equal.

Comment: I tend to agree; however I think the designers of the standard library like to be a little more rigorous in their thinking than you or me :)

Answer (score 2):

Generally the algorithms are coded so you only need to know equivalence once, at the end.  So requiring two calls instead of one is not an unreasonable burden.

Requiring only less-than with a `bool` result makes things simpler.